# How can I transpose a table to a vertical list in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose

I'd like to take a table of values and transpose them into a vertical list, but in a way that alternates the values - i.e. a diagonal transpose (avoiding referencing the same row or column sequentially)

So this:

[image: table]

Becomes something like this:

[image: vertical list]

[Here is a link to a spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12C2xANwVnMIf362vCtgfX6-VfGt8Y7F28qEGJyxzFT0/edit?usp=sharing) with some dummy values that shows what I am trying to accomplish

I would prefer to avoid using anything that requires a Google script - and use a formula instead.

Comment: _"avoiding referencing the same row or column sequentially"_ — the desired results show `D3` and `D2` next to each other, and ditto for `A5` and `A4`, so they do not meet the criteria you set. Is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)? If so, please describe the _problem_ you are trying to solve and tell what you are really trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
=let(Σ,B2:E5,
     Λ,{tocol(Σ),tocol(makearray(rows(Σ),columns(Σ),lambda(r,c,r-c)))}, cols_,index(Λ,,2),
       choosecols({filter(Λ,cols_=0);sort(filter(Λ,cols_<0),2,);sort(filter(Λ,cols_>0),2,)},1))
```

[image]

Comment: This matches the OP's desired results, but `D3` and `D2` end up next to each other, and ditto for `A5` and  `A4`, so they do not meet the criteria the OP set.

Comment: Well to be honest I didn't really really notice the phrase (*avoiding referencing the same row or column sequentially*) until now;) So I dont know... will wait on OP to clarify!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution:

```
=LET(r,B2:E5,
     n,COLUMNS(r),
     v,TOCOL(r),
     TOCOL(
           {
            REDUCE(,SEQUENCE(n),LAMBDA(a,c,{a;CHOOSEROWS(v,SEQUENCE(n-c+1,1,c,n+1))}));
            REDUCE(,SEQUENCE(n-1),LAMBDA(a,c,{a;CHOOSEROWS(v,SEQUENCE(c,1,-n*c,n+1))}))
           },1))
```

Comment: This matches the OP's desired results, but `D3` and `D2` end up next to each other, and ditto for `A5` and  `A4`, so they do not meet the criteria the OP set.